# Etymology of a name

Tags: etymology, yiddish

I'm not sure if this is on topic, but here goes.

What is the etymology of the yiddish forename Feiga? פיגא, פייגא in its yiddish spelling. My first thought was that it comes from the word Feige which is both German and yiddish for fig. However, I was later told that it comes from the word Vogel. Which is also a shared word for bird. Though in yiddish both are pronounced the same.

Feig (פייג)—fig. Feigel(פייגל)—bird.

If anyone can help me with this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Vote to close bc this needs expertise in a language other than German.

Answer (score 1):

*Der Vogel* is a Standard German term. The Standard German diminutives are *das Vögelchen* and *das Vög(e)lein*. In the southwestern dialects, they say *le* instead of *lein*, so it becomes *das Vögele*.

And that's spoken *das Feig(a)le* in those dialects.

Yiddish is also from the southwest. Mind you, you cannot give anything on the Latin writing as Yiddish is meant to be written in Hebrew characters that had to be adapted to fit the Germanic phonetic inventory.

Comment: _Vogel_, _Vögele_, and _Vögelin_ are also German last names.